# How to get differences between two arrays, like a diff (added, deleted)?

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I have two snapshots of data, in arrays, such as this:

Array number 1:

```
array{
    'foo' => 'foo_value',
    'bar' => 'bar_value',
    'baz' => 'baz_value'
}
```

Array number 2:

```
array{
    'foo' => 'foo_value_new',
    'bar' => 'bar_value',
    'baz' => 'baz_value',
    'xyz' => 'added_value'
}
```

I want to get two arrays, one with added elements, one with deleted ones:

Array with added new data:

```
array{
    'foo' => 'foo_value_new',
    'xyz' => 'added_value'
}
```

Array with deleted data:

```
array{
    'foo' => 'foo_value',
}
```

How could this be archieved in php?
Do any array_* functions have similar behaviour?

Comment: On google, `php array diff` yields [this wonderful PHP manpage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)...

Comment: Thanks! This actually only solved one of my problems, but rest was solved in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is not any inbuilt function to return two array try a simple way

```
 $str = array(
    'foo' => 'foo_value',
    'bar' => 'bar_value',
    'baz' => 'baz_value'
);
$str1=array(
    'foo' => 'foo_value_new',
    'bar' => 'bar_value',
    'baz' => 'baz_value',
    'xyz' => 'added_value'
);
$add= array_merge(array_diff($str, $str1), array_diff($str1, $str));
print_r($add);//Array ( [foo] => foo_value_new [xyz] => added_value )

$del = array_diff($str, $str1);
print_r($del); //Array ( [foo] => foo_value )
```

Comment: The OP asked for 2 arrays in return, one is new/modified data and the other is deleted.